# How to extract inner text of multiple Paragraph tags which are nested withing an anchor tag

Tags: xpath, html-agility-pack

Here is the code:

```
<a id='Letter1'>
<p>Dear Sir, </p>
<p>This is with.........</p>
<p>I would be.......</p>
<p>Hoping to hear from you soon</p>
<p>Regards.</p> 
</a>
```

Using Xpath I want to extract the inner text of all the Paragraph tags which are contained inside the anchor tag as a single text entity.

The final result i want is

```
string letterBody= document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//XPATH QUERY").innerText;
```

where letterBody="Dear Sir, This is with...................Regards."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to just get the `<a>` element and you will get all the text nodes which are under `<a>` as its innertext.
So your xpath would be **`/a[@id='Letter1']`** or just **`/a`**.